# How can I call a stored procedure from Crystal Reports?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have a stored procedure that takes a user ID and calculates their balance with a really simple query and returns it. I want to add this to a crystal report in my application. The only problem is, Crystal Reports wants me to set a value for the procedure, and setting a single value for it would be useless to me.

I have everything grouped by the `User.ID` field, and I want to use `User.ID` as the parameter for the query. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of options

1.
Create a new stored procedure that returns all of the user ID's then create a sub-report for each user linked to the main report of user IDs.

2.
If you have the option, change the stored procedure to accept a value like 'All' for the username and have the stored procedure return all values when All is the value.  Not 100% sure if this will work, just a brainstorming idea.

Answer (score 2):

Within your main report you can add a subreport that will use the stored procedure as a data source and the userId as a parameter.

Your main report will list all the userID you are interested in and pass each of them individually to subreport

It has been quiet some time since I last worked with crystal reports so I do not remember the technical details, only the main concept